# setBackgroundColor with TypedArray Id Color

Tags: android, colors, resources, adapter

I have a problem when using the `setBackgroundColor()` method on an object of type View .
The colors I want to use are declared in an array in my file `strings.xml`

```
<array name="nav_news_colors">
        <item>@color/nav_1</item>
        <item>@color/nav_2</item>
        <item>@color/nav_3</item>
</array>
```

And in `colors.xml` :

```
<color name="nav_1">#919fa1</color>
<color name="nav_2">#ffa2a6</color>
<color name="nav_3">#a28bc3</color>
```

Then, on my `ActivityMain.java` :

```
navMenuNewsColors = getResources()
                .obtainTypedArray(R.array.nav_news_colors);


navNewsItems = new ArrayList<NavNewsItem>();

navNewsItems.add(new NavNewsItem(navTitles[0], navColors.getResourceId(0, -1)));
navNewsItems.add(new NavNewsItem(navTitles[1], navColors.getResourceId(1, -1)));
navNewsItems.add(new NavNewsItem(navTitles[2], navColors.getResourceId(2, -1)));
```

```html
public class NavNewsItem {
 
 private String title;
 private int color;
 
 public NavNewsItem(){}

 public NavNewsItem(String title, int color){
  this.title = title;
  this.color = color;
 }
 
 public String getTitle(){
  return this.title;
 }
 
 public int getColor(){
  return this.color;
 }
 
 public void setTitle(String title){
  this.title = title;
 }
 
 public void setColor(int color){
  this.color = color;
 }
}
```

But I can't use it in my adapter for `setBackgroundColor` :

```
View imgColor = (View) convertView.findViewById(R.id.v_color);
imgColor.setBackgroundColor(navDrawerItems.get(position).getColor());
```

Comment: Post code for "getColor()" method please. And what's the reason behind the fact you can't use it?

Comment: Hi Nik, i edit my code.

Comment: But why are you passing resource id as the color? I'm not sure, but you should try setBackgroundResource instead of setBackgroundColor

Comment: Thx Nik, it works, I had not seen this instead of setBackgroungColor.

Comment: May i post it as an answer so i can grow some rep please?

Comment: I have one last question, it doesn't work out :                                        TextView txtCount = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.counter);
txtCount.setTextColor(navDrawerItems.get(position).getColor());

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to change  `navColors.getResourceId(0, -1)` to `navColors.getColor(index, defValue)`, and then you can use both `setBackgoundColor` and `setTextColor` with the same code